# Getting nearest (store,etc,) in terms of nearest route

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

first time posting here, have been finding answers to my queries here. So I need to find the `“real” nearest location` (perse a hospital or store) from the nearest route from a specific point to the hospital or store.

So far, I have used `haversine’s formula` from my PHP code as a query to my database, and it returns the nearest location in terms of points and coordinates. But what I want is the nearest in terms of the nearest route so it would really be the nearest.

I need the query of the nearest to be on the server side. As the nearest data would be passed on to the Arduino microcontroller. Arduino sends GPS coordinates, then receives nearest `store/hospital`. This is the only problem that I encountered. Maybe I can get some suggestions with reference materials on how to go about this problem. Thank you :)

The only thing I can think of is maybe having a google map in the web/website and then passing the MySQL result there and maybe using distance-matrix or directions API, and then returning it to the PHP file.

EDIT: So far I have used Distance Matrix API from Google Maps. Now my problem is, how do I get or is it possible to output the result from the API into my PHP file in JSON format?

Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNkc2.png) or similar so I can parse it in my Arduino UNO and Android app.

Here is the code of my PHP file

```
<?PHP
//DLSUD
$CrashLat = 14.3234;$CrashLon = 120.959432;
//Pagamutan
$HosLat1 = 14.323003;$HosLon1 = 120.961666;
//St Paul
$HosLat2 = 14.323321;$HosLon2 = 120.962895;
?>

<script>    

    function init() {

    var origin1 = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat('<?php echo $CrashLat;? 
    >'), parseFloat('<?php echo $CrashLon;?>'));

    var destinationA = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat('<?php echo 
    $HosLat1;?>'), parseFloat('<?php echo $HosLon1;?>'));   

    var destinationB = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat('<?php echo 
    $HosLat2;?>'), parseFloat('<?php echo $HosLon2;?>'));   

    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();  

    service.getDistanceMatrix(  {       
        origins: [origin1, origin1],        
        destinations: [destinationA, destinationB],     
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,  
        durationInTraffic: true,
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: false   
        }, callback);   
    }

    function callback(response, status) {       
        if (status == 'OK') {           
            var origins = response.originAddresses;         
            var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;       
            for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {          
                var results = response.rows[i].elements;            
                for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {              
                    var element = results[j];               
                    var distance = element.distance.text;               
                    var duration = element.duration.text;               
                    var from = origins[i];              
                    var to = destinations[j];           
                }       
            }
            console.log(results[0].distance);
        }   
    }    

</script>    
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? 
key=API_KEY&callback=init">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question it seems. Here is the code.

```
<?PHP
//DLSUD
$CrashLat = 14.3234;$CrashLon = 120.959432;
//Pagamutan
$HosLat1 = 14.323003;$HosLon1 = 120.961666;
//St Paul
$HosLat2 = 14.323321;$HosLon2 = 120.962895;

$APIrequest="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json? 
units=metric&origins=".$CrashLat.",".$CrashLon."&destinations=".$HosLat1.
",".$HosLon1."|".$HosLat2.",".$HosLon2."&mode=walking&key=API_KEY";

$DistanceMatrixResult = file_get_contents($APIrequest);

$Object = json_decode($DistanceMatrixResult, true);

$HospitalDistance1 = $Object['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['value'];
$HospitalDistance2 = $Object['rows'][0]['elements'][1]['distance']['value'];

if ($HospitalDistance1 > $HospitalDistance2) {
    echo $HospitalDistance2;
}
else {
    echo $HospitalDistance1;
}

?>
```

Just replace the assignments of hospitals to a SQL query to your database (Using Harvesine's formula, then setting LIMITS and sorting the result).

NOTE: mode=driving(default) is kind of buggy, makes long unnecessary routes at certain instances. Better use mode=walking/transit.